# How to purge old computers from the Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing old computers on a domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/118743/removing-old-computers-on-a-domain)

We've got a Windows Server 2008 instance (R1) and have several computers that are no longer present. Still, they show up in the AD.

**Is there a way to purge old computers that have not been online for X months from the AD?**

Answer (score 1):

Check out PowerGUI from Quest, you can use it to run a search for workstation objects that have not been active in X number of days, and then delete them. Do be careful with the tool, it's very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

JoeWare has a script that will query for old computers. This works for 2000/2003, I'm not sure how nicely it will work on a 2008 Native domain, though.

http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/oldcmp/index.htm

There's also an article on the MS Scripting center about how to do it:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/11/19/how-can-i-find-old-computer-accounts.aspx

**Edit**: JScott's answer from a previous thread seems to be the best answer:

```
dsquery computer -inactive 10 -limit 0
```

Where 10 is the number of weeks of inactivity